# How to define a controller with multiple parameters but only send one in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

He guys!

I am creating the next controller

```
function add($action,$data){

}
```

Wich gives me functionality for the next url:

> controller/add/proyect/0

but this is a multiple purpose controller.

So, i need to call it like this:

> controller/add/proyect

I dont want to send data, i just want to add the proyect.

when i do that, the compiler sends me the error:

> Missing argument 1 for add()

This is what i tried:

```
function add($action,$data=null){

}
```

and

```
function add($action,$data=false){

}
```

But still not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: "*It is not working*" is not useful. Please explain, if you get an error message (if so, which one) or if the results differ from your expectation (if so, how).

Comment: PHP functions allow for optional parameters, by saying `$data=null` you are by default setting  $data to null, Also explain what you mean by multipurpose function

Comment: **DEFINITE** duplicate of [using a PHP function but missing out the parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015895/using-a-php-function-but-missing-out-the-parameters)

Comment: I use `$data=false` all the time -- how isn't that working?

Comment: @AmalMurali I already wrote the error message. Please read the entire text.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus why did you link to another duplicate? lol

Comment: @user3368975: I've read the entire answer. But at the end of the answer, you're just saying "*But still not working.*" without actually saying what error message you're getting or what doesn't work.

Comment: @RUJordan Facepalm, the correct answer is `function add($action=null,$data=null){` <-- cannot leave just `$action` without giving it a default.

Answer (score 0):

The two examples where you set a default for data should be working fine.  You don't need to set a default for all parameters.

Your issue probably lies within the function itself.  You might have the function set up to only return a value if $data is equal to something.  Do you have any lines in the function that say

```
if(!$data){
```

or maybe

```
if(empty($data)){
```

We definitely need to see the whole function before we can give you an answer why it's not working.